# Problem adding --with parameter to nmake build

Tags: perforce

I'm comfortable with make and scons on unix/linux, but am having a hard time using nmake to build php with a perforce php api included in the build. I can successfully build php no problem, but when I go to build with a reference to the perforce api, I get an access denied error, but the dir I'm referencing has fully opened permissions. From what I can find, my syntax is correct, and if I try anything else I get an error saying the command isn't valid.

```
 C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\php5.3-201106102030>configure --disable-all --enable
-cli --with-perforce=<C:\p4api>,shared
Access is denied.
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar errors before.  A couple things to check:

- Look in the directory containing p4php and verify that you see "README.txt" and "RELNOTES.txt"
- Remove the brackets from around `<C:\p4api>`

If none of that works you can always contact Perforce support.  They can help troubleshoot.